# What's the etymology of sound' in 'sound in damages, tort, contract'?

Tags: etymology, legalese

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/185129):

> **6.  *to sound in damages:*** in legal use, to be concerned only with damages. Also ***to sound in tort, to sound in contract,*** etc.
>
> > 1780 M. Madan *Thelyphthora* II. 153 There is not one [change] which does not sound in damages, as our lawyers speak.

1. Which homonym and false cognate listed in [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sound#etymonline_v_23921) (below) fits 'sound'? Is this actually a third?

> v<sup>1</sup>: early 13c., sounen "to be audible, produce vibrations affecting the ear," from Old French *soner* (Modern French *sonner*) and directly from Latin *sonare* "to sound, make a noise," "to sound," from PIE *swene-, from root *swen- "to sound." From late 14c. as "cause something (an instrument, etc.) to produce sound." Related: Sounded; sounding.
>
> v<sup>2</sup>: "fathom, probe, measure the depth of," mid-14c. (implied in sounding), from Old French *sonder,* from *sonde* "sounding line," perhaps from the same Germanic source that yielded Old English *sund* "water, sea" (see sound (n.2)). Barnhart dismisses the old theory that it is from Latin *subundare.* Figurative use from 1570s.
> 2. How did 'sound' (v. 1 or 2) semantically shift to mean 'to be concerned only with'?

#### A couple of examples from English judges

[*Contract Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (2018 8 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Text-Cases-Materials/dp/019880816X/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) p. 93.

> ...The law simply imposes an obligation on
> the party who made the request to pay a reasonable sum for such work as has been done
> pursuant to that request, such an obligation **sounding in** quasi contract or, as we now say, in
> restitution.

[*Anson's Law of Contract* (2016 30 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ansons-Law-Contract-Jack-Beatson/dp/0198734786/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=ZW82SGPZDB8D0GKSVMV4). p. 180.

> *In the Investors Compensation Scheme* case: [...]
>
> The
> exclusion from assignment clause, ‘Any claim (whether **sounding in** rescission for
> undue inﬂuence or otherwise)’ was interpreted as if it had read, ‘Any claim **sounding
> in** rescission (whether for undue inﬂuence or otherwise)’. This construction meant
> that only claims for rescission, and *not for damages*, against the building societies were
> excluded from the assignment.

Comment: I'd suggest "resonates" followed by a common-law restriction. For example, a claim was resonant for money damages rather than compensation in kind, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that legal use of *sounding* arose by working backward from the notion of a case's being "heard" by a court for purposes of resolving a particular claim. Here is the first part of the entry for *hearing* in *Black's Law Dictionary*, fourth edition (1968):

> **HEARING.** Proceeding of relative formality, generally public, with definite issues of fact or of law to be tried, in which parties proceeded against have right to be heard, and is much the same as a trial and may terminate in final order. [Citations omitted.] Synonymous with trial, and includes reception of evidence and arguments thereon. [Citation omitted.] It is frequently used in a broader and more popular significance to describe whatever takes place before magistrates clothed with judicial functions and sitting without jury at any stage of the proceeding subsequent to its inception, and may include proceedings before an auditor. [Citations omitted.]

A hearing, understood broadly, is thus a proceeding at which any suit or claim is brought to a magistrate or judge for adjudication. It is no great stretch, then, to suppose that *sounding* is the aspect of a claim that, under law, merits a hearing by a magistrate. Here is the entry for "sounding in damages" in *Black's Law Dictionary*:

> **SOUNDING IN DAMAGES.** When an action is brought, not for recovery of lands, goods, or sums of money, (as is the case in real or mixed actions or the personal action of debt or detinue,) but for damages only, as in covenant, trespass, etc., the action is said to be "sounding in damages." [Citations omitted.]

In other words, when a plaintiff brings a case to court for a hearing on the subject of damages, the plaintiff's action "sounds" in the hearing in relation to the subject that the law narrowly deems appropriate for that action. A suit for trespass, for example, would sound in damages (the appropriate compensation for the tort of trespass under law) but would not sound in replevin (recovery of lost goods) because a suit for trespass is not the appropriate action to file if the outcome desired is restoration of unlawfully taken property. The hearing is strictly attuned to the sounding that makes sense in connection with the type of compensation sought.

---

A second interpretation of *sounding* arises from a broader notion of "wholeness." This sense of the *sound* as an adjective receives considerable attention in Noah Webster, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YRdFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT106&dq=%22founded+in+right+and+law;+legal;+valid;+not+defective%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji24Sg-s7iAhVmrFQKHfFHD7MQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22founded%20in%20right%20and%20law%3B%20legal%3B%20valid%3B%20not%20defective%22&f=false), volume 2 (1832), which bundles the legal definition of *sound* in the company of numerous other definitions related to being entire, unbroken, healthy, and nondefective:

> **SOUND,** *a.* ... **1.** Entire; unbroken; not shakey, split or defective; as *sound* timber. **2.** Undecayed; whole; perfect, or not defective; as, *sound* fruit; a *sound* apple or melon. **3.** Unbroken; not bruised or defective; not lacerated or decayed; as a *sound* limb. **4.** Not carious; not decaying; as, a *sound* tooth. **5.** Not broken or decayed; not defective; as, a *sound* ship. **6.** Whole; entire; unhurt; unmutilated; as, a *sound* body. **7.** Healthy; not diseased; not being in a morbid state; having all the organs complete and in perfect action; as, a *sound* body; *sound* health; a *sound* constitution;  a *sound* man; a *sound* *horse*. **8.** Founded in truth; firm; strong; valid; solid; that cannot be overthrown or refuted; as, *sound* reasoning; a *sound* argument; a *sound* objection; *sound* doctrine; *sound* principles. **9.** Right; correct; well founded; free from error; orthodox. 2 Tim. i. "Let my heart be sound in thy statutes." Ps. cxix. **10.** Heavy; laid on with force; as, *sound* strokes; a *sound* beating. **11.** **Founded in right and law; legal; valid; not defective; that cannot be overthrown; as, a *sound* title to land; *sound* justice.** **12.** Fast; profound; unbroken; undisturbed; as, *sound* sleep. **13.** Perfect, as intellect; not broken or defective; not enfeebled by age or accident; not wild or wandering; not deranged; as, a *sound* mind; a *sound* understanding or reason.

Nevertheless, having made a case for the adjective *sound* as, in legal settings, being allied with notions of rightness and freedom from defects, Webster tucks an explanation of the expression "to sound in damages" under an entry for the verb *sound* in the sense of emitting audible noise or vocalization:

> **SOUND,** *v.i.* [**1.**] To make a noise; to utter a voice; to make an impulse of the air that shall strike the organs of hearing with a particular effect. We say, an instrument sounds well or ill; it sounds shrill; the voice sounds harsh. "And first taught speaking trumpets how to *sound*." *Dryden*. **2.** To exhibit by sound or likeness of sound. This relation *sounds* rather like a fiction than a truth. **3.** To be conveyed in sound; to be spread or published. "From you *sounded* out the word of the Lord." 1 Thess. i. ***To sound in damages*, in law, is when there is no specific value of property in demand to serve as a rule of damages, as in actions of tort or trespass, as distinguished from actions of debt &c.** *Ellsworth*.

It thus appears that Webster, after all, finds the origin of "sounding in damages" not in notions of legal wholeness or rectitude, but in the emitting of something audible. In this respect, an interesting comment posted beneath this answer by EL&U site participant Steve may be pertinent:

> I've always thought "sound" in this context is related to the engineering practice of striking something to test its integrity. Something "sounds in damages" means "if tested, will resonate with the remedy of damages". Cf. "Sound/unsound reasoning".

There are indeed several senses of *sounding* that involve testing the depth or validity of a thing being measured or assessed. But it remains to be demonstrated whether *sounding* in the legal sense arose from these operations.

Comment: The connection to hearing is no doubt a desirable aspect of the metaphor, but I've always thought "sound" in this context is related to the engineering practice of striking something to test it's integrity. Something "sounds in damages" means "if tested, will resonate with the remedy of damages". Cf. "Sound/unsound reasoning".

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that the law-specific use of "sound" was imported from Law French.  I see in *The Law-French Dictionary Alphabetically Digested*, Published by Nutt and Gosling, London, 1718, an entry for "Sourdant" ("-ant" being the French ending roughly equivalent to "-ing" in English), meaning "arising or springing out".  Also "Soudra" = "They arose".  (These are on pp 134 and 135).

Answer (score -1):

It seems @SvenYargs missed a remote possibility:

Compare reconstructed Proto-Germanic [*sundraz](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/sundraz) "separate, isolated, alone", reflected in English *sunder, asunder, sundry*, German *sondieren, sondern, besonders, absondern*., etc. Since our *sounding* did not make the list, I am less than convinced by my own idea, on phonetic grounds.

It makes sense semantically, at least. Not only are claims for restitution *isolated* from the main case (at least where the criminal/civil distinction holds, though these may be combined through *adhesion*), but after holding a claim for damages there might be an incentive to separate the claimed property from the losing party.

### Legalese is known to conserve archaic features of language to the point that it becomes incomprehensible. Unless this turn of words was a recent creation, the similarity to modern meanings of *sound* may be coincidental, or formed by analogy if the original meaning had been all but forgotten.

In the same wane, he preposition *in* may hold additional information. Ger. *Sühne* "repenance, atonement" is cognate to *sound* "whole, healthy" (and Ger. *gesund* "healed, healthy", *gesamt* "summed, completed"), indeed, via [*swono](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/sw%C5%8Dn%C5%8D). In that sense, a connection to *sound* "sono, noise" at the root level is thinkable, as verbalized appology, ie. repanance. And if we *seek and claim damages* it is thinkable to *repay in damages*, though this is fickle.